# Unknown parameter [data_type] on mapper of type [knn_vector]

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

Based on the [documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/knn/knn-index/#knn_vector-data-type), I am trying to create an index with the nested vector field using `byte` as the underlying data type:

```json
PUT docs_byte
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1, 
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "ideas": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "vector": {
                        "type": "knn_vector",
                        "dimension": 384,
                        "data_type": "byte"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error `unknown parameter [data_type] on mapper [vector] of type [knn_vector]`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `byte` `data_type` is only supported by the the `lucene` engine, so you need to declare your field like this:

```
PUT docs_byte
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1, 
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "ideas": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "vector": {
                        "type": "knn_vector",
                        "dimension": 384,
                        "data_type": "byte",
                        "method": {
                            "name": "hnsw",
                            "space_type": "l2",
                            "engine": "lucene",        <------ add this
                            "parameters": {
                                "ef_construction": 128,
                                "m": 24
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this (and tried again now with the copy of your code to make sure). Same error. The error seems to be during parsing, so it seems to have nothing to do with what follows the problematic line...

Comment: What version of OpenSearch are you using?

Comment: I execute the queries in the dashboard. I assume it is running the latest stable version.

Comment: That doesn't tell me what version you're using. What does `GET /` return?